# Apache virtual hosting with domain and subdomain

Tags: apache, virtualhost, tomcat8

Can someone point me what I am doing wrong here?
On one server instance having both httpd and tomcat8 I need to host 2 sites as below:

```
http://localhost:8888/ - should be accessed as www.example.com   
http://localhost:8080/webapp1 - should be accessed as webapp1.example.com
```

I have tried VirtualHost in httpd.conf but only www.example.com works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8888/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8888/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName webapp1.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/webapp1/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost.com:8080/webapp1/
  <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sounds like a DNS CNAME setting issue for webapp1 subdomain.

Comment: @smozgur thanks for your response. I have both example.com (@) and webapp1 (CNAME) pointing to same server IP.

Comment: Sorry, trying to make sure because DNS takes some time to resolve and it makes me crazy often. You did not do the CNAME settings in the last 15-20 minutes, right? Also, I often need to change browser to check my newly entered subdomains, just because browser cache as it insists to show from cache.

Comment: btw, CNAME supposed to point to @, not the IP address. I know it is probably not the issue either, but worth to mention.

Comment: @smozgur I did the CNAME settings about 4 hours ago. CNAME points to @ which points to IP address.

Comment: One last thing - as I still believe it is DNS (Actually what was the error you see). Did you make sure about subdomain at : https://www.whatsmydns.net/

Comment: that's a good point! I'll check and let you know

Comment: @smozgur it seems like the DNS changes did propogate to all regions.

Comment: ok then, what is the exact error you get in the browser? in this case it should be something other than  "can't find server".

Comment: its "This page can’t be found. No web page was found for the web address:"

Comment: Hmm, is both 8080 and 8888 configured correctly? I know it is annoying to answer these questions but I am trying to find out what's wrong. In fact I never use ProxyPass but it shouldn't affect how port is listened by httpd.

Comment: @smozgur it's not at all annoying because I really appreciate you help. Infact your comment made me check if http://localhost:8888/webapp1 is working. It wasn't! I added name="localhost" to tomcat's server.xml <Host>. Now both sites work as I want them to be. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: great to hear that! :) happy 2017!

Answer (score 0):

Verify virtual configuration syntax using “httpd -S” as shown below. When everything is setup properly, it just displays “Syntax OK”.

```
# /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
Syntax OK
```

For more clarity refer here - [How To Setup Apache Virtual Host Configuration](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/Apache-Virtual-Host/)

And I hope you have added the server name with your localhost address in your hosts file (C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts).
Like this
     `127.0.0.1 example.com`

Please do share what solution you found out.